# nginx 499 while upstream server does not receive the request

Tags: nginx

I run a backend data application and use nginx as a reverse proxy. The service user or client side reports some request timeout and I really find a number of 499 codes in the nginx access log.

It is strange that I cannot find any request record in my application log file which is set to logger every received request. The client side timeout is set to 300ms. I think this is enough to receive the request for application sever from nginx.

Someone can tell me why application not log the request or how to distinguish the application sever receive the request.

I want to fix the reason and many thanks for your help.

Comment: did you find out the reason??